# Gradle error in IntelliJ IDEA extractRepoFileDependencies error

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I got the following error after importing a almost bare-bone Gradle Java project in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2.  From the event log window:

```
12:51:24 PM Gradle 'gradletest' project refresh failed:
            Cause: org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor.extractRepoFileDependencies(Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ConfigurationContainer;Ljava/util/Collection;Ljava/util/Collection;ZZ)Ljava/util/List;
            Gradle settings
```

In the Gradle settings window for the project, I chose "Use default Gradle wrappers (recommended)", and default for all the rest which is mostly empty any way.

Gradle environment:

```
/usr/local/bin/gradle

$ gradle -version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.0
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-07-01 07:45:34 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b6ead6fa452dfdadec484059191eb641d817226c

Groovy:       2.3.3
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.6.0_65 (Apple Inc. 20.65-b04-462)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.9.4 x86_64
```

Comment: We can't read your Evernote links.  You *really* should post them here instead.

Comment: @Makoto But the site does not allow me to post images.

Comment: Posting a link to your image through imgur is better than not having any image to show at all.

Comment: Well, I got the copyable text added.   I beg you to revert your negative vote so people can see the post.  Please.

Answer (score 0):

Use gradle 1.10 with IntelliJ 13.1.2, or upgrade IntelliJ to 13.1.4

Comment: Is upgrading from 13.1.2 to 13.1.4 free?